# load a Word document inside an iFrame

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to load a Word document inside ASP.NET page, but it is getting opened through Word that is installed in machine.

Can anyone provide some info on how to load a Word document inside an `iFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to export the file using word and upload it as a pdf and embed it on page as an object.

http://www.ehow.com/how_5775382_load-pdf-within.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible directly..

you can try this way

for just displaying documents in browser without needing user to have office installed, u can use google doc viewer or zoho doc viewer

http://docs.google.com/viewer

https://viewer.zoho.com/home.do

hope this helps...